# How to use the Django ORM for creating an interface like MySQL admin that connects to multiple databases

Tags: django, mysql-python, django-orm, cx-oracle

So I'm fairly new to Django development and I started using the cx_Oracle and MySQLdb libraries to connect to Oracle and MySQL databases. The idea is to build an interface that will connect to multiple databases and support CRUD ops. The user logs in with the db credentials for the respective databases. I tried not using the Django ORM (I know you may ask then what is the point)but then it is still all a learning endeavor for me. Without the Django ORM (or any ORM for that matter),I was having trouble persisting db connections across multiple requests(Tried using sessions).I need some direction as to what is the best way to design this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django uses connection pooling (i.e. few requests share the same DB connection). Of course, you can write a middleware to close and reinitialize connection on every request, but I can't guarantee you will not create race conditions, and, as you said, there is no point to do so.

If you want to make automatic multi-database CRUD, you'd better use some other framework (maybe, Flask or Bottle), because Django is optimized in much aspects for content sites with pre-set data scheme.

Also, it's not quite simple application, and maybe it's not a good way to learn some new technology at all. Try starting with something simpler, maybe.

Comment: Would you recommend using SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: I'm not sure if any ORM is good for tat task. Actually,these systems just take raw data from the tables, they don't need any additional logic or repreentation abstractions.